# Intermittent ng-infinite-scroll not triggered in feature test

Tags: capybara, selenium-chromedriver, capybara-webkit

I have an angular app which is using http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll

In one of my feature tests, I am trying to simulate the user scrolling to the bottom of the page, it's pretty straight forward, there is an expectation that the page has the selector '.spinner' after scrolling down to the bottom.

50% of the time it works, 50% it fails.  When I watch the test live in Chrome, the scroll bar goes down to the bottom of the page and nothing happens.  If I throw a breakpoint in there, and then use my mouse scrolling up and down over and over, nothing happens.  It's as if infinite scroll is dead. If I keep rerunning the test, eventually it will work (**deep sigh**), so it's one of those annoying bogus things that only make our love for Capybara that much stronger.

I've tried scrolling the page with:

```
page.execute_script "$('body').scrollTop(99999999999)"
```

and

```
page.execute_script "window.scrollTo(0, 99999999999)"
```

both of them yield intermittent results...  I also tried iterating over a loop and scrolling the page in chunks to literally make it look like it's being dragged down to the bottom.  Same nonsensical results.

I am now having to solve my problem by manually triggering the method that gets called by infinite scroll:

```
page.execute_script "angular.element('.listing').scope().nextPage();"
```

Which absolutely sucks and kind of defeats the purpose of an integration test.

Can anyone offer any suggestions how to resolve this severe case of obnoxious bogusness?

Comment: When the test fails are there any errors in Chromes console log?

Comment: No, there are no errors.